# too much space for align if I use double space

Tags: spacing, vertical-alignment, align

I'm using a Latex template. They provide the following command for double space

```
%% To produce output with the desired line spacing, the argument of
%% \spacing should be multiplied by 5/6 = 0.8333, so that 1 1/2 spaced
%% corresponds to \spacing{1.5} and double spaced is \spacing{1.66}.
\def\normalspacing{1.25} % default line spacing
```

I've tried to use their command but it is not working. I've decided to use `\usepackage{setspace}` and use

```
\begin{spacing}{1.5}
...
\end{spacing}
```

Now the double space works but I have noticed too much space before and after `align`. As you can see from the following picture how much space between the blocks.

[image]

How to control the vertical space for `align` mode?

This is a sample that mimics my work

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\begin{spacing}{1.5}


hhs haha ahaha ha aha ahahaha ha ahaha aha 
ahahah ahaha ahahahaha ahah ah hhs haha ahaha ha aha ahahaha ha ahaha aha  ahahah ahaha ahahahaha ahah ah hhs haha ahaha ha aha ahahaha ha ahaha aha ahahah ahaha ahahahaha ahah ah  ahah ah hhs haha ahaha ha aha ahahaha ha ahaha aha 

\begin{align}
x = 
\begin{bmatrix}
ss & ss & ss & ss \\
ss & ss & ss & ss \\
ss & ss & ss & ss \\
ss & ss & ss & ss
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}

hhs haha ahaha ha aha ahahaha ha ahaha aha 
ahahah ahaha ahahahaha ahah ah hhs haha ahaha ha aha ahahaha ha ahaha aha  ahahah ahaha ahahahaha ahah ah hhs haha ahaha ha aha ahahaha ha ahaha aha ahahah ahaha ahahahaha ahah ah

\begin{align}
x = 
\begin{bmatrix}
ss & ss & ss & ss \\
ss & ss & ss & ss \\
ss & ss & ss & ss \\
ss & ss & ss & ss
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
\blindtext


\end{spacing}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Dont' leave blank line before and after `align`.

Comment: @HarishKumar, you are right but this is really hard to read the code.

Comment: You can put a `%` instead of blank line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Never leave empty lines before and after `align`, `equation` etc environments. If you want put a `%` instead of blank lines. Then spacing will be alright.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\onehalfspacing
hhs haha ahaha ha aha ahahaha ha ahaha aha
ahahah ahaha ahahahaha ahah ah hhs haha ahaha ha aha ahahaha ha ahaha aha  ahahah ahaha ahahahaha ahah ah hhs haha ahaha ha aha ahahaha ha ahaha aha ahahah ahaha ahahahaha ahah ah  ahah ah hhs haha ahaha ha aha ahahaha ha ahaha aha
%
\begin{align}
x =
\begin{bmatrix}
ss & ss & ss & ss \\
ss & ss & ss & ss \\
ss & ss & ss & ss \\
ss & ss & ss & ss
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
%
hhs haha ahaha ha aha ahahaha ha ahaha aha
ahahah ahaha ahahahaha ahah ah hhs haha ahaha ha aha ahahaha ha ahaha aha  ahahah ahaha ahahahaha ahah ah hhs haha ahaha ha aha ahahaha ha ahaha aha ahahah ahaha ahahahaha ahah ah
%
\begin{align}
x =
\begin{bmatrix}
ss & ss & ss & ss \\
ss & ss & ss & ss \\
ss & ss & ss & ss \\
ss & ss & ss & ss
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
%
\blindtext


\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

If you want blank lines before `align` in your code, you can insert

```
\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\abovedisplayshortskip}{0pt}
```

inside your `spacing` environment

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\begin{spacing}{1.5}
\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\abovedisplayshortskip}{0pt}


hhs haha ahaha ha aha ahahaha ha ahaha aha
ahahah ahaha ahahahaha ahah ah hhs haha ahaha ha aha ahahaha ha ahaha aha  ahahah ahaha ahahahaha ahah ah hhs haha ahaha ha aha ahahaha ha ahaha aha ahahah ahaha ahahahaha ahah ah  ahah ah hhs haha ahaha ha aha ahahaha ha ahaha aha

\begin{align}
x =
\begin{bmatrix}
ss & ss & ss & ss \\
ss & ss & ss & ss \\
ss & ss & ss & ss \\
ss & ss & ss & ss
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}

hhs haha ahaha ha aha ahahaha ha ahaha aha
ahahah ahaha ahahahaha ahah ah hhs haha ahaha ha aha ahahaha ha ahaha aha  ahahah ahaha ahahahaha ahah ah hhs haha ahaha ha aha ahahaha ha ahaha aha ahahah ahaha ahahahaha ahah ah

\begin{align}
x =
\begin{bmatrix}
ss & ss & ss & ss \\
ss & ss & ss & ss \\
ss & ss & ss & ss \\
ss & ss & ss & ss
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
\blindtext


\end{spacing}

\end{document}
```

[image]